# get the value out of a long string with multiple values

Tags: java

I have a string:

```
{"name":"value", "name2":"value2" ... "name3":"value3"}
```

I would like to search by a name and get the value of it.

But I never saw this format before.. so I have no idea what to look for. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Where did you get that String from?

Comment: hint: www.json.org

Comment: This string is called by name JSON, search for JSON-Java

Comment: I got the string from a http request. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Its JSON formet use json jar to handle this formet... 
 Ex: JSONObject jsonObject  = new JSONObject (yourString)  ;   
 for getting name value you should use 
  jsonObject. get ( "name" ) ;

Comment: This is less informative than the comments above, please put a little effort into your answers.

Answer (score 0):

As this is JSON, you need a JSON parsing library. This example uses [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(someURLhere);

// access "name1" using node.get("name1").textValue(), etc
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like JSON, although I could be wrong.
If you're working in Javascript, you can do this:

```
var JSONobject = {"name":"value", "name2":"value2" ... "name3":"value3"};
```

and then get your desired value with:

```
JSONobject.name;
```

(This should return "value")

Other languages have libraries available. PHP has JSON support buildin (json_decode), and for Java my person favorite is GSON.